# find index number of uppercase character in a string

Tags: python

```
string = "heLLo hOw are you toDay"
results = string.find("[A-Z]") <----- Here is my problem
string.lower().translate(table) <--- Just for the example.
>>>string
"olleh woh era uoy yadot"
#here i need to make the characters that where uppercase, be uppercase again at the same index number.
>>>string
"olLEh wOh era uoy yaDot"
```

i am need to find the index number of the uppercase characters in the string above, and get a list (or whatever) with the index numbers in order to use again on the string, to bring back the uppercased characters at the same index number.

maybe i can solve it the the re module, but i didn't find it any option to give me back the index numbers.
hope it understandable, i have done a research but couldn't find solution to it.
Thanks.

BTW, i am using python 3.X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something along this line, just need to modify it a little bit and collect those start positions into an array etc:

```
import re

s = "heLLo hOw are you toDay"
pattern = re.compile("[A-Z]")
start = -1
while True:
    m = pattern.search(s, start + 1) 
    if m == None:
        break
    start = m.start()
    print(start)
```

Comment: @PeterPeiGuo: You can even do `pattern_search = re.compile(…).search` and directly call `pattern_search(s, start+1)`.  This makes the code run faster (if this matters).

Comment: Why `pattern_search = re.compile(…).search` and `pattern_search(s, start+1)` makes the code faster (to a considerable extent)?

Answer (score 1):

```
string = "heLLo hOw are you toDay"
capitals = set()
for index, char in enumerate(string):
    if char == char.upper():
        capitals.add(index)

string = "olleh woh era uoy yadot"
new_string = list(string)
for index, char in enumerate(string):
    if index in capitals:
        new_string[index] = char.upper()
string = "".join(new_string)

print "heLLo hOw are you toDay"
print string
```

which shows:

```
heLLo hOw are you toDay
olLEh wOh era uoy yaDot
```