# For string with lower then UPPER . Give position when UPPER starts . Python

Tags: python, for-loop, boolean, uppercase, lowercase

If i have a string

```
ex = 'aaatttgggatgaATG'
```

and I want to find the index where the lowercase ends

so in this case it would be

```
indx_lower = 13
```

how would i get that value ?

would I have to do a for loop where i checked the boolean for each element in the string ?

like this ?

```
total_indx = range(0,len(ex))

for p,k in zip(ex,total_indx):
    if upper print k ?
```

ya i don't know how i would do this . . .

Comment: The last lowercase letter is at index 12. Remember they start at 0

Comment: Maybe the answer of this question will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204712/find-index-number-of-uppercase-character-in-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is not to use a for loop:

```
>>> print re.search("[A-Z]", "aaatttgggatgaATG").start()
13
```

`re.search()` returns a `MatchObject` object, and you can ask where it begins by calling its `start()` method. (But if there is no match, `re.search()` will return `None`).

Answer (score 3):

```
next(i for i,j in enumerate(ex) if j.isupper()) - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use re

```
import re

ex = 'aaatttgggatgaATG'

print ex.index(re.search('[A-Z]', ex).group())
```

Comment: what is the 's' towards the end ?

Comment: sorry that was the string, but i changed it to 'ex'

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in range(0, len(ex)):
    if ex[x].isupper():
        print x
        break
```

Comment: `enumerate` would be more idiomatic than `range` here.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> ex = 'aaatttgggatgaATG'
>>> re.search("[A-Z]", ex).start()
13
```